# parsing XML with python using ElementTree

Tags: python, xml

I have an XML file which is shown below.

```
<queries>
 <query name="Select" statement="select * from customer_organization">
  <filters>
   <filter id="Select" name="Customer" type="text"></filter>
   <filter id="Select" name="Start Date" type="date"></filter>
   <filter id="Select" name="End Date" type="date"></filter>
  </filters>
 </query>
 <query name="Insert" statement="insert into customer_organization">
  <filters>
   <filter id="Insert" name="From Date" type="date"></filter>
   <filter id="Insert" name="To Date" type="date"></filter>
  </filters>
 </query>
</queries>
```

Now I need to get the names in the "query" tag by parsing it with python.I have tried with elementtree.But it is displaying nothing on my console.Can you please help me with it as I am newbie to python.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree
e = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse('form.xml').getroot()
for s in e.findall('query'):
    print(s.get('name'))
```

Comment: I tested your code and I am getting on two lines: "select" and "insert".

Comment: Why i don't get output then

Answer (score 0):

So I've just tested your code. It works fine.

```
>>> Select
>>> Insert
```

Another approach is to use [**`xpath()`**](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html)

```
import lxml.html

ttt = """<queries>
 <query name="Select" statement="select * from customer_organization">
  <filters>
   <filter id="Select" name="Customer" type="text"></filter>
   <filter id="Select" name="Start Date" type="date"></filter>
   <filter id="Select" name="End Date" type="date"></filter>
  </filters>
 </query>
 <query name="Insert" statement="insert into customer_organization">
  <filters>
   <filter id="Insert" name="From Date" type="date"></filter>
   <filter id="Insert" name="To Date" type="date"></filter>
  </filters>
 </query>
</queries>"""


page = lxml.html.fromstring(ttt)

print page.xpath('.//query/@name')
```